# how to use PerfProvider classes to VM Sphere to get the statistics of ESXi 6.0

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, health-monitoring, esxi

```
ManagedEntity vm = new InventoryNavigator(si.getRootFolder()).searchManagedEntity(
            "HostSystem", "localhost.localdomain");

PerfProviderSummary pps = perfMgr.queryPerfProviderSummary(vm);
```

i am getting these stats using perfMgr.getDescription()

Key:65537
 PerfCounter:mem.usage.average
 Level:null
 StatsType:absolute
 UnitInfo:percent

but i want to know the values related to counter ID

if anyone working on VMware monitoring please try to give the solutions thanks